# How do I get the address value with specific name using jsonpath

Tags: jsonpath

**JSON**

```
[{
        "name": "aaaa",
        "address": "word1",
        "newHouse": false,
        "age": 8
    },
    {
        "name": "bbbb",
        "address": "word2",
        "newHouse": true,
        "age": 9
    },
    {
        "name": "cccc",
        "address": "word3",
        "newHouse": false,
        "age": 12
    }
]
```

**JSONPath**

```
$[*][?(@.name==['aaaa'])].address
```

Comment: What you have in the title should do find. Can you show what you're getting or what else you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$[*][?(@.name=='aaaa')].address
```

OR

```
$..[?(@.name=='aaaa')].address
```